# Try to sum the incoming data

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import date

class Goals(models.Model):
      calories= models.FloatField(max_length=10)
      protein=models.FloatField(max_length= 4)
      carbohydrates= models.FloatField(max_length= 4)
      fats= models.FloatField(max_length=4)   
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Macros(models.Model):
      name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
      calories= models.FloatField(max_length=10)
      protein=models.FloatField(max_length= 4)
      carbohydrates= models.FloatField(max_length= 4)
      fats= models.FloatField(max_length=4)
      goals = models.ForeignKey(Goals, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

here is my models and trying sum the userinput of macros and user can input many so want add it the old things and the new things

and my view.py

```
def index(request):
      # macros = Macros.objects.all()
      # goals = Goals.objects.filter(user=request.user)
      macros = Macros.objects.filter(user=request.user)
      protein_count=''
      for macro in macros:
              macro['protein'] += [protein_count]
      return render(request, 'macro/index.html', {'macros': macros, 'protein_count': protein_count})
```

like i dont really know what am doing

Comment: What code have you had so far to add them? Where do you want to save it?

Comment: def index(request):
      # macros = Macros.objects.all()
      # goals = Goals.objects.filter(user=request.user)
      macros = Macros.objects.filter(user=request.user)
      protein_count=''
      for macro in macros:
              macro['protein'] += [protein_count]
      return render(request, 'macro/index.html', {'macros': macros, 'protein_count': protein_count})

Comment: and i want to save it to show my index page

Comment: Can you update your question with that view?

Comment: add the console output so we can see what django says about it

Comment: if you want to count then why you use string `protein_count= ''` instead of `protein_count= 0`? And why `macro['protein'] += [protein_count]` if it should be rather `protein_count += macro['protein']`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand problem but for me `counting`/`sum` means

```
  protein_count = 0

  for macro in macros:
      protein_count += macro['protein']
```

eventually with `sum()`

```
  protein_count = sum( macro['protein'] for macro in macros )
```

---

But maybe it could be done using only model - like using function `SUM()` in pure `SQL`

---

**EDIT:**

Maybe you need [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/) and something like

```
result = Macros.objects.filter(user=request.user).agregate(Sum('protein'))

protein_count = result["protein__sum"]
```

Comment: im useing django

Comment: see [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/) in Django